# What is the longest professional championship drought ever?

Tags: trivia, records

Is there a professional sports franchise in the history of the world that has gone longer without a championship than the Chicago Cubs (105 years and counting)?

Comment: are you asking about a sport in particular? are you asking about a competition in particular?

Comment: Any professional sports franchise. Soccer, cricket, rugby, football, etc.

Answer (score 2):

**Gloucestershire County Cricket Club**, one of the oldest first-class counties, have never won the **County Championship** (arguably the foremost domestic cricket competition in England and Wales) since the competition started in 1890, meaning that as of 2014 they have gone **124 years** without winning it.